# How to disable ssh in Wind River v.7 linux?

Tags: linux, ssh

How to disable ssh in Wind River v.7 linux? Can anyone help me? Below command given an error.

update-rc.d ssh disable

update-rc.d: /etc/init.d/ssh: file does not exist

I want to disable ssh but i can use serial console

Comment: sshd or openssh-server maybe ?

Comment: Isn't Wind River Linux an OS for embedded systems? If so, if you disable ssh, how are you going to connect to your embedded system?

Comment: Welcome to Super User.  It would appear that you have accidentally created two accounts.  You should use the [contact form](http://superuser.com/contact) and select “I need to merge user profiles” to have your accounts merged.  In order to merge them, you will need to provide links to the two accounts.  For your information, these are http://superuser.com/users/516828/user516828 and http://superuser.com/users/516838/yuvan-raj.  You’ll then be able to [edit], comment on, and accept answers to this question.